# Is it possible to get out of the radioactive waste pits in DOOM E1M3?

Tags: doom

In DOOM E1M3 (Toxin Refinery) there is a radioactive waste pit at the start,

[image: radioactive waste at start]

and a couple in the middle (just before you get the blue keycard).

[image: radioactive pits in middle]

My question is; if you fall into these pits, is it possible to get out? Like through a secret lift or something? (though the "Official" DOOM FAQ v6.666 doesn't say anything about that in the secrets section)
Thanks!

Comment: There is always the no clipping cheat which will climb out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For the first area:**

Nope, you're dead if you fall.

**For the second area:**

If you fall into the center, then yes, you can get out.  There is a switch at the bottom you can hit to raise the whole platform.  IIRC, it also has a large health pack in the center of it.

If you fall off into the sides however, there is no way to get out other than death.

Comment: Perhaps my memory is making me second guess, but I thought there was a radioactive waste pit that rose if you hit space on one of the sides.  Could have easily been another map..

Comment: well, there is a platform and a switch out of the toxic in the middle pit that rises if you push it. (there's also a medkit... that comes in handy sometimes :)